How can I know the stripe_id in the subscription when the renew is monthly, using webhooks
I want to know what subscription is renewing, I have the stripe_id in my database so when the date to renew is coming, I want to know which subscription was renew but I cant get the stripe_id when I use the Stripe CLI, I use the stripe trigger invoice.payment_succeeded event, I have this
So I can't find the subcription ID
I want to receive the stripe id

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The Subscription ID that the Invoice is associated with should be on the Invoice object.
